# Преобразование массива точек в кривые Безье или любые другие подходящие кривые

Tags: java, android, c++, массивы, алгоритм

Пишу "рисовалку", т.е. пользователь ведет пальцем по экрану, а я получаю массив точек {X1,Y1; X2,Y2; X3,Y3; .... Xn, Yn}

Вопрос: Как мне этот массив преобразовать в кривые Безье (их можно рисовать на `Canvas` стандартными методами)? Язык не важен, мне главное понять математическую модель

Вопрос2: существуют ли стандартные библиотеки для решения данной задачи?

Comment: А в чём трудность, собственно? Действуем [по определению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5): берём сумму произведений координат на полиномы Бернштейна.

Comment: Java  PathIterator не подойдет для этого?

Comment: То есть вы хотите опорные точки получить?

Comment: Да. Плюс нужно понимать через какой промежуток их брать

Comment: Вам нужна библиотека или Вы готовы сами реализовывать? Это не очень сложный алгоритм в плане реализации. Разумеется, если Вы начнёте копать, то наткнётесь на убойную математику. Но, повторюсь, не при реализации.

Comment: Готов использовать библиотечку, но в любом случае пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Так что там с библиотечками?